# On the fly / dynamic CakePhp 3 Validation and FormHelper

Tags: validation, cakephp, formhelper

I am creating a 'form editor' in CakePHP.

The interface allows the user to choose validations to apply to the fields, e.g. Numeric, Email etc.

As such I need to dynamically create validation for the model based on the user input. For this I can use the Validation object: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html

I want to take advantage of the features of FormHelper, for example, automatically outputting error messages for fields.

I can see how to use a hard-coded validator from the model to do this by setting the validator in the context option for Form->create() - but how do I use a customer $Validator object which has been dynamically created?

Clarification:

I have some code in my controller:

```
//get the form configuration
$form = $this->Forms->get($id, ['contain'=>['FormFields'=>['Validations']]]);


//set up validation based on the configuration

$validator = new Validator();
foreach($form->form_fields as $field){
  ...
  if($field->required) $validator->notBlank($field->field_name);

}


$table = TableRegistry::get($form->type);

$table->setValidator($validator);
```

Unfortunately setValidator() is not a method of TableRegistry.

If I set the validation up in the model, I would need the $id parameter to look up the correct form configuration.

Comment: Your question somehow reads as if the actual problem is missing, given that it doesn't really matter how an object was created, once it has been created, you just use it no matter its origin.

Comment: Thanks ndm. I guess then my question is how? I can create a Validator object. I can run validations using that object, but how can I set the Table (?) to use this so that the form helper has access to the errors?

Comment: It may help if you'd show where and how you create the validator, and how it is being used for validation. If you create it in for example `validationDefault()` (or whatever validation method in the model), or via the `Model.buildValidator` event, then you don't need to do anything, the validation errors would normally be stored on the entity, so in most situations there should be no need to touch the validator object manually in the first place, you'd just need to pass the entity to the form helper.

Comment: Sure, sorry. I am defining the validation object in the controller because I am using a url parameter to define which form configuration to use. There is one model which stores form config and this then generates forms for different models. I am going to see if I can define the validation object in the model instead but I’m not sure if I’ll be able to access the url parameter there? Next on my list to try out.

Comment: There should be various ways to inject the value into the model layer, for example via the `validate` option in `patchEntity()`/`newEntity()`, or using a simple setter method. If you show some example code of your controller and model I might be able to give you some more precise advice.

Comment: Thanks ndm, I can see how to specify a validator which is hard-coded in the model via `newEntity`, `patchEntity` and in `$this->Form->create()` - but I can't see how to specify a Validator object created in the controller...

Comment: Of course I can define my own setValidator() function in the model, and that worked I will publish the solution. Gaaaahh.

Answer (score 1):

I added the following code to my model:

```
protected $validator = null;  

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator){
  if($this->validator != null) return $this->validator;
  return $validator;
}

public function setValidator(Validator $validator){
  $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

So the default validator can effectively be set via the setValidator method.

Then in my controller:

```
//get the form configuration
$form = $this->Forms->get($id, ['contain'=>['FormFields'=>['Validations']]]);


//set up validation based on the configuration

$validator = new Validator();
foreach($form->form_fields as $field){
   ...
   if($field->required) $validator->notBlank($field->field_name);

}


$table = TableRegistry::get($form->type);

$table->setValidator($validator);
```

I hope this is useful for others.